# How to put clash colors together?

Tags: color

I am asked to put three specified colors together to form a pie chart, a colorful ring, some colorful diamonds and etc. Those three colors together are really ugly.

Are there any tricks to make it more pretty?

PS: Those three colors are:

> ## #99CC00
>
> ## #0164C2
>
> ## #000000

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i00u0.jpg]

Meanwhile, I promise I am way beyond the age of receiving a homework.

Comment: A visual example would be more useful!

Comment: This smells like homework to me.

Comment: LOL! You're right, it definitely does!

Comment: What is wrong with these colors together?

Comment: @Matt uh...ugly? I tried to split them up, blur them, make it 3D, and add gradient in between. But nothing would make it better.

Comment: i must be color blind or have broken eyes

Comment: change all the color  :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The painter [André Lhote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Lhote) wrote in his treaty ("Traité du paysage") that you can use dense bright colors if you separate them with large black lines, use some neutral greys on the display, and let large patches of the white background.

Comment: I've tried these suggestions. They are not perfect, but it does get better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use tints. 10%, 20%, 50%, etc.

Your pie chart could be three different grays, diamonds could be tints of the green, the ring could be tints of blue.

Just because you have to use all three doesn't mean all three have to be next to one another in the same chart.

Answer (score 1):

The blue and the green actually work pretty well together.  Not saying they are beautiful, but they do go together well.  The black is rather abrupt, though.  You might try giving the black area a 'glossy button' look to try to minimize the intensity of the black compared to the other two colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use those colours, you have to use those colours.

The only thing I might try is putting a little white space between them, which it sounds like you've already tried.

I don't think any 3d effects will help.